# How I can search a field in sql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, search

I have a login page with username and password fields. I want to search an inputted username in my table called 'mytable' and, if this table have such a username, display his data in grid view.
take me linq answer

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     CostumerDataContext costum = new CostumerDataContext();
     LOGIN2 item = new LOGIN2();
     var islogin = (from u in costum.LOGIN2s 
                         where u.Username == txtUser.Text 
                         && u.Passwrod == txtPass.Text select u).ToList();
     if (islogin.Count>0)
     {
         Dgw.Visible = true;
         Dgw.DataSource = from u in costum.LOGIN2s  select u;
      }
      else
      {
           Label3.Visible=true;
      }
 }
```

Comment: You mean you have passwords stored in clear text in a DB table? Wow

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: it doesent correctly

Comment: Can you please post what is wrong with the code? Is it not compiling, giving unexpected or wrong output, runtime failure, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting `data` from `database` on basis of `username` and `password` but you are assigning the `gridview` data of `whole table`.

You need to bind gridview with filtered data.

```
var islogin = (from u in costum.LOGIN2s 
                         where u.Username == txtUser.Text.Trim() 
                         && u.Passwrod == txtPass.Text.Trim() select u).ToList();
if (islogin.Count>0)
{
  Dgw.Visible = true;
  Dgw.DataSource = islogin;
  Dgw.DataBind();
}

else
{
  Label3.Visible=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     using (CostumerDataContext costum = new CostumerDataContext ())
     {

         LOGIN2 item;
         item  = (from u in costum.LOGIN2s 
                     where u.Username == txtUser.Text 
                     && u.Passwrod == txtPass.Text select u).FirstOrDefault();
        if (item != null)
        {
            Dgw.Visible = true;
            Dgw.DataSource = item;
        }
        else
        {
            Label3.Visible=true;
        }
    }
}
```